# shell can't find my ruby gem/ node library

Tags: ruby, macos, node.js, rubygems, npm

I want to interact with http app, so I find [htty](http://htty.github.com) and [http-console](https://github.com/cloudhead/http-console).

I use

```
gem install htty
```

Or

```
npm install http-console
```

But my shell seems can't these commands. So I need add to my PATH or something else?

Edit:
I am using OS X Lion and I have *npm* and *gem*,both packages are successfully installed. I try to type the two commands in terminal, but commands not found appeared.

Comment: You should probably mention which operating system you're on.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `gem` and `npm` installed. Enter the following command and see if they are installed (and what versions):

`gem -v && npm -v`